# How to insert two or more R.string into one TextView

Tags: java, android, resources, textview

I want to insert two or more R.strings into one single textview. How do I do this? I know how to insert two direct strings into a single textview, separated by `+` such as below:

```
text1.setText("I am" + "John");
```

but to insert two or more R.strings, I can't debug it.

My attempt:

```
text1.setText(R.string.myname + R.string.John);
```

is not working. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Please don't just say something "is not working".  Provide the exact error message or exception you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

You should do

```
text1.setText(getString(R.string.myname) + getString(R.string.John));
```

Comment: oh thanks!! it worked!. you made my day =D =D.
but, i want to ask, what is so different between not put `getString` and put it?

Comment: When you don't put getString its just a hex value which the setText doesn't understand. The getString returns the string after reading it from the Resources based on the id you passed